# radio button not aligned properly in table cell

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want to have four images for selection in radio button, however, when generating the radio button, the first image in td always have bigger width than others image, and the radio button is beside the image but not on top of the image, how can I make the first image have same width like others image in td. 
Here are my codes:

```
             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg"/>
                 <label for="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg"><img src="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"/>
                 <label for="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"><img src="zSepCGRnUc.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"/>
                 <label for="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"><img src="WkzJIGctSz.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="vsIClceVUI.jpg"/>
                 <label for="vsIClceVUI.jpg"><img src="vsIClceVUI.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

        </tr>
```

And here is the outlook image: 
     [image]

And here is the css I used:
    .multiline
    {
      padding:0px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      height: 100px;
      width: 50%;
      margein:0px
    }

```
.left-div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: linen;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.right-div {
    margin-left: 108px;

}
.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.hide { position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px; width:1px; height:1px; }

.spacer {height:4px; }

.beta {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:1000px;}
table td {word-wrap:break-word;}
.alpha {width:300px;height:300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a float on each element?
In the CSS, define a class and add something like:

```
.box {
width: 50px;
float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```css
.some_class td{
 position:relative;
}
.some_class td input{
 position:absolute;
    top:34%;
    left:0;
}
.some_class td label img{
 display:inline-block;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="some_class">
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg"/>
  <label for="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSXYu.jpg?s=64&amp;g=1" width="64" height="64" alt="Feel Happy" />
  </label>
 </td>

 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"/>
  <label for="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSXYu.jpg?s=64&amp;g=1" width="64" height="64" alt="Feel Happy" /></label>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"/>
  <label for="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSXYu.jpg?s=64&amp;g=1" width="64" height="64" alt="Feel Happy" /></label>
 </td>

 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="vsIClceVUI.jpg"/>
  <label for="vsIClceVUI.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSXYu.jpg?s=64&amp;g=1" width="64" height="64" alt="Feel Happy" /></label>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```css
<style>
.box {
width: 50px;
float:right;}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg"/>
                 <label for="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg"><img class="box" src="SeVYzlSRmE.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"/>
                 <label for="zSepCGRnUc.jpg"><img class="box" src="zSepCGRnUc.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"/>
                 <label for="WkzJIGctSz.jpg"><img class="box" src="WkzJIGctSz.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>

             <td><input type="radio" name="emotion" id="vsIClceVUI.jpg"/>
                 <label for="vsIClceVUI.jpg"><img class="box" src="vsIClceVUI.jpg" alt="I'm sad" /></label>
             </td>
         </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```